# CSS Key animation: How do I make an image expand and shrink properly?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

Here's a fiddle showing CSS key animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/ryurage/Q2ELp/

I'm trying to get the image to grow and fill the majority of the window triggered by some interaction like a hover or click and hold.  After that, I want the image to shrink back to it's original position on the page.

Two problems with this: 
 1. the image expands out but does so from the top left corner of the page.  I'd like it to grow from it's original position.
 2. The image collapses when it does the shrink animation.  All you see is the border.  How do I avoid this and just see the image shrink?

What CSS an I missing?

## HTML:

```
<div id="div2"></div>
```

## CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px dashed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(http://www.terrystickels.com/db_3squaresto8squares5.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-transition: .25s;
  -moz-transition: .25s;
  -o-transition: .25s;
  -ms-transition: .25s;
  transition: .25s;
}
#div2 {
  position: static;
  float: right;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
#div2:active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Your html says div2 does stuff on hover, but your css has it as `:active`. I'm confused as to what your goals are.

Comment: Sorry for the markup comment being misleading.  It's a vestige.  What I want is to click and hold, hover, I don't really care some interaction to make the image expand and shrink in the way I state in my question above.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will have to hard code the 'left' and 'top' values of #div2

```
#div2 {
  position: static;
  float: right;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

Should be changed to

```
#div2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 110px;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
}
```

Please see my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nWp4P/2/